# 403 error when submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, hosting

Hi I have a form that is submitted after a JS file has completed validation checks

in the form the main line is

```
   <form  style='background-color:ccc' id='form1' name='form1' method='post'  action='dual_process.php' > ;
```

The code for submitting the form is (This calls a JS script)

```
   <input class="buttn" type="button" name="su" id="su" value="Confirm and Submit Details"  <? echo "onclick='$validate;' " ?> />
```

After the JS script have validated the form the following line is executed

```
    if (!msg)  { 
var frm = document.getElementById("form1");
frm.submit() ;
```

This all worked fine until I moved to a new web host now when I submit the form I get the following error

Forbidden

You do not have permission to access this document.

Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong OR if there is something that the new host does not like (Old host Simple Web Hosting New one IDAQ )

Thanks I advance for any help

Mick

Comment: What does $validate in PHP hold? It's used on the onclick= event. Also, you might wanna check if your htaccess is the right one, it might be that your old host was routing the request properly due to it.

Comment: Look into the `error.log`. A 403 can occur for mod_security setups.

Comment: can you manually browse to 'dual_process.php' ? or does that throw a 403 also?

Comment: I can manually browse the dual_process.php file

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Try use double quotes to the form attributes: `action="dual_process.php"`, and the others.

The most common reason for the 403 error is that directory browsing is forbidden for the Web site.
Check if you can directly access the "dual_process.php" page, and maybe a better response can give you the administrator of that server.

Comment: Single- or Double- quotes shouldn't matter. You can even use NO quotes if the property has no spaces in it..